# Export to excel - ASP problems

Tags: sql, excel, asp-classic

I'm trying to export a HTML table to excel but unfortunately, I can't get it going.

I have a table that is populated from a database table based on the results of a previous pages filter form. That from works fine and filters fine, display the output in a table.

Now when I try getting it to download the table via ASP, it downloads the entire SQL table instead. I've tried storing the results again in a hidden form, and downloading via that; doesn't work. When it moves to the next page, it loses the data for each field and instead takes on the entire SQL table.

I've been using Response.ContentType and Response.AddHeader as I understand this is how you export to excel/csv.

If anyone can help me so that I could possible have this in the same page with an hyperlink/button click beginning the download, that would be brilliant.

**Edit:**

```
    <tr>
        <td name="StationReference"><a href="Inventory_details.asp?Name=<%=statRS("StationReference")%>&InventoryID=<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>"><%=statRS("StationReference")%></a></td>
        <td name="RepairStatus"><%=statRS("RepairStatus")%></td>
        <td name="SSD"><%=statRS("SSD")%></td>
        <td name="Motherboard"><%=statRS("Motherboard")%></td>
        <td name="PSU"><%=statRS("PSU")%></td>
        <td name="NetworkLogin"><%=rsGlobalUsers("NetworkLogin")%></td>
        <td name="RepairDate"><%=statRS("RepairDate")%></td>
        <td name="Location"><%=statRS("LocationName")%></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="repairsEdit.asp?InventoryID=<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>"><img src="../Images/Icon_edit.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Edit" /></a></td>
    </tr>
```

The above code displays the table after the filter/search has taken place

The following code is the hidden form

```
    <form id="hiddenDownload" name="hiddenDownload" action="downloadTable.asp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="TheSearch" value="<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="StationReference" value="<%=statRS("StationReference")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="RepairStatus" value="<%=statRS("RepairStatus")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="SSD"value="<%=statRS("SSD")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="Motherboard" value="<%=statRS("Motherboard")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="PSU" value="<%=statRS("PSU")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="rtRepairedBy" value="<%=rsGlobalUsers("NetworkLogin")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="rtRepairDate"value="<%=statRS("RepairDate")%>">
        <input type="hidden" value="<%=statRS("LocationName")%>">
        <input type="submit" value="Download">
    </form>
```

Comment: If you remove the response.contenttype directive in the page what does the html table look like? are you retrieving the file in Internet Explorer or another browser? are you actually removing the fields you do not want or are you just setting them to display hidden?

Comment: Removing Response.ContentType doesn't do anything, just shows the table as normal.

I've tried it in internet explorer, chrome and firefox. That fields I want are all that are displayed, other than an "edit" column, which I haven't put into the hidden form.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, this will onyl be used in IE as it's part of an intranet and a lot of the older stuff is only really compatible with IE. What I was hoping to do was similar to the first page, where the filter takes place, then where it's fed into the table I was hoping to feed it into the hidden form with a submit button showing, that would submit to the seperate page to process and output the excel file.

Thanks for all your help though, appreciated.

Comment: ok so correct me if I am wrong but here is what you are doing. Step 1 user sets filters for a page on a table. Step 2 filters are passed via javascript onChange event to hidden fields in a form. Step 3 user hits submit button passing the filter parameters to the subsequent page. Step 4 SQL procedure is run on the new page accepting the additional filter parameters. Step 5 html table is built on the page using the results. Step 6 Response.ContentType directive allows users to download html table as excel file.

Comment: Sort of. The logic is as follows:
Page 1 - user filters/searches using form.
Page 2 - SQL statements etc are in place and searches the database table, displaying the appropriate data in the table. A button/hyperlink is needed on this page to export to excel.
Page 3 should be page where the excel file is generated and offered to open/save. Shouldn't show anything on the page itself, if possible not directing away from page 2.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: ok so to be sure, pages 2 and 3 are identical correct? The only difference between the two is that page 3 has the response.ContentType added at the top of the page? and also the button should be removed.

Comment: Yep, other than the button and the "edit" column, which isn't needed in the spreadsheet, it's identical. I've tried with and without the hidden forms on both pages, but it just appears that the RecordSet isn't carrying on from Page 2 to Page 3

Comment: can you add the code you use to save the filters from page 1 on page 2? If there is an issue it likely comes from there.

Comment: If Request.QueryString("Search") = "" Then
  TheSearch = Request.Form("txtRepairSearch")
 Else
  TheSearch = Request.Form("Search")
 End If

Each textbox is retrieved like that

Comment: If Request.Form("selLocation") = "" OR Request.Form("selLocation") = "0" Then
  rtLocation = ""
 Else
  rtLocation = "AND tblLocation.LocationID = " &Request.Form("selLocation") & "" 
 End If

Each select box like that

Comment: If Request.Form("selRepairType") = "" OR Request.Form("selRepairType") = "0" Then
  rtRepairType = ""
 ElseIf (Request.Form("selRepairType") = "1") Then
  rtRepairType = "AND tblRepairTracking.SSD = '1'"
 ElseIf (Request.Form("selRepairType") = "2") Then
  rtRepairType = "AND tblRepairTracking.Motherboard = '1'"
 ElseIf (Request.Form("selRepairType") = "3") Then
  rtRepairType = "AND tblRepairTracking.PSU = '1'"
 ElseIf (Request.Form("selRepairType") = "4") Then
  rtRepairType = "AND tblRepairTracking.SSD = '1' AND tblRepairTracking.Motherboard = '1' AND tblRepairTracking.PSU = '1'"
 End If

Comment: Previous one was for the checkboxes. And then theres the SQL statement, which takes each name "TheSearch", rtRepairType, RepairedBy etc etc, and pulls that information from the database.

Comment: I kind of wanted to see your question edited with something like <input type="hidden" name="sellRepairType" value='<%=Request.From("sellRepairType")%>'> I assume you have code like this right?

Comment: apologies, will do that now

Comment: Hm, not sure why stackoverflow is only showing the end tags, any idea why?

Comment: ok so it seems like you are storing the record set and not the filter parameters. You should be passing filter parameters to the next page in the hidden field not record set values.

Comment: When you say "filter parameters", do you mean the results of the search, or what was put into the search originally? Sorry, pretty new to ASP

Comment: what was put into the search orignally

Comment: Will see if I can get somewhere further then. thanks for your help, hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove Response.ContentType precisely so you could show the table format. What the actual html table looks like is more important as only IE will behave in the best fashion with this command. As stated here in comment 7:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=319428#c7

If you have just set the columns to display hidden they will still be shown. The Response.ContentType is best only for internet explorer. For multiple browsers you should look into other methods to produce an excel report. If you need to support other browsers you need to make sure that the only thing on your page is the table. Nothing should be hidden or otherwise changed to not be shown.

**Edit:**
Updated based on comments

Pages 2 and 3 should be identical to each other not just similar. If you are not able to just copy the page as is with no changes then something is wrong. the following example should illustrate this:

**Page 1:**

```
<Form id="form1" action="page2.asp" method="post">
    Sell Location: <input type="text" name="sellLocation"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Page 2:**

```
<%
    sLoc = Request("sellLocation")

    Set objCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
    objCmd.CommandType = 4 'Stored Proc
    objCmd.CommandText = "YourStoredProcedure"
    objCmd.Parameters.Refresh
    objCmd.Parameters("sellLocation") = sLoc 
    Set obj_rst = objCmd.Execute
%>

<Form id="form1" action="page3.asp" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="sellLocation"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="download">
</form>

<tr>
    <td name="StationReference"><a href="Inventory_details.asp?Name=<%=statRS("StationReference")%>&InventoryID=<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>"><%=statRS("StationReference")%></a></td>
    <td name="RepairStatus"><%=statRS("RepairStatus")%></td>
    <td name="SSD"><%=statRS("SSD")%></td>
    <td name="Motherboard"><%=statRS("Motherboard")%></td>
    <td name="PSU"><%=statRS("PSU")%></td>
    <td name="NetworkLogin"><%=rsGlobalUsers("NetworkLogin")%></td>
    <td name="RepairDate"><%=statRS("RepairDate")%></td>
    <td name="Location"><%=statRS("LocationName")%></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="repairsEdit.asp?InventoryID=<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>"><img src="../Images/Icon_edit.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Edit" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

**Page 3:**

```
<%
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", " filename=yourspreadsheetname.xls"

    sLoc = Request("sellLocation")

    Set objCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
    objCmd.CommandType = 4 'Stored Proc
    objCmd.CommandText = "YourStoredProcedure"
    objCmd.Parameters.Refresh
    objCmd.Parameters("sellLocation") = sLoc 
    Set obj_rst = objCmd.Execute
%>


<tr>
    <td name="StationReference"><a href="Inventory_details.asp?Name=<%=statRS("StationReference")%>&InventoryID=<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>"><%=statRS("StationReference")%></a></td>
    <td name="RepairStatus"><%=statRS("RepairStatus")%></td>
    <td name="SSD"><%=statRS("SSD")%></td>
    <td name="Motherboard"><%=statRS("Motherboard")%></td>
    <td name="PSU"><%=statRS("PSU")%></td>
    <td name="NetworkLogin"><%=rsGlobalUsers("NetworkLogin")%></td>
    <td name="RepairDate"><%=statRS("RepairDate")%></td>
    <td name="Location"><%=statRS("LocationName")%></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="repairsEdit.asp?InventoryID=<%=statRS("InventoryID")%>"><img src="../Images/Icon_edit.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Edit" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Note how between page 2 and 3 all I had to do was delete the form and add the response.contenttype directive. The way you seem to pass values to your page now I imagine this format would be impossible.